# Draw functions in Typed Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

So I wrote a prototype [Wolfenstein3d-style ray-caster](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/raycast/) in Racket. Understandably it's not blazingly-fast when run at higher-resolutions, so I'm trying to switch to Typed Racket.

My question is if there a way to do graphics (generally) in Typed Racket? For my particular purpose, all I need to be able to do is draw a line, and display/slice a bitmap.

What I've tried:

- `Big-bang` from `2htdp/universe` (what I originally used in regular racket) doesn't work with typed racket, and it's a complicated macro, so unlike an untyped-function I can't opaquely `require/typed` it.
- `racket/draw` is class based, and support for classes in typed racket is experimental, so I wasn't surprised when I couldn't find `typed/racket/draw` version yet.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of Racket, you can use classes and `racket/draw` in Typed Racket. For example:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.0.1.13.
-> (require typed/racket/draw)
-> (make-bitmap 300 300)
- : (Instance Bitmap%)
(object:bitmap% ...)
```

but it's indeed still experimental so you may hit some bugs or limitations. In particular, for now you won't be able to pass GUI objects between typed and untyped modules.

(please submit [bug reports](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/) if you find bugs)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the drawing operations in an untyped module, and call them from a typed module.